# Aws cloud9 IDE error 'Language server could not be loaded; some language features have been disabled' pops up

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cloud9

My cloud9 IDE slowed down and froze:

- I installed react and AWS amlify-cli
- I run `amplify add auth`
- I chose default options
- I run `amplify push`
- Cloud9 terminal started work slower and slower

Then this error pop up:

> Language server could not be loaded; some language features have been disabled.

I stopped and changed my instance type from `t2.micro` to `t2.small` and reboot instance.

It did not solve it.